# How to get content to stick to bottom of a side bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site that has a side bar, in that side bar I'd like some feedback buttons that stick at the bottom of the sidebar. I've got the feedback buttons in a div called feedback which is in a div called body. Then in my scss file I have:

```
.card{
  position: relative;

  .feedback{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the structure of the HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header"></div>
  <div class="card-body">
    SIDEBAR CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="feedback">
    FEEDBACK BUTTONS
  </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, I'm not really sure what to do next.

Comment: For the card or the feedback?

Comment: Well, maybe `fixed` is not a good idea anyway. Please show the HTML structure for this, or search for ["sticky footer"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5dsticky%20footer).

Comment: I've updated the question with the structure of the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using FlexBox for the layout?

It is supported pretty well though all major browsers nowadays.

Take a look at this

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

**Edit:** I thought I'd give you some example code

```
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}


.card-body{
   flex: 1;
}
```

This should do it. Make sure to set the min-height. If you want it to cover the whole viewport you can use `100vh`.

Comment: Thanks, this mostly works, however a small problem is that the height of the feedback area itself can change, so at the moment the footer gets bigger from the bottom in order to accommodate, but I'd rather it expand from the top. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is you set the `min-height` very small. Then your **.card-body** will most likely exactly be the size of its content (plus padding). Doing this the Feedback footer will always be directly attached to the content. And if it grows, it does not look weird. Basically the gap between content and feedback will be gone.

Comment: Also the side bar is at height 100% which means that the feedback buttons end up displaying below the bottom of the page

Comment: Oh I didn't know you wanted that. In That case you probably have to use the `position: fixed` approach by Umbeveloper. Then you just have set the `max-height` of your **.card-body** accordingly and set it to `overflow: scroll`, to have it scrolling when its content gets too big. When the feedback grows you might have to change the **.card-body**'s height with JavaScript.

Comment: Accoding to your comment on the other answer you want the feedback "to be pushed down" when the content reaches the bottom of the screen. Here you are saying, that you don't want that to happen. Which one is it now?

Comment: Sorry I think I explained myself poorly, the sidebar has height:100 which means when using the flex box approach you posted the feedback ends up being displayed below the bottom of the screen, regardless of how much content is in the card-body.

Comment: are you sure, that you set `height: 100vh` on the **.card** and not on .**card-body** ?  Cause when I tried it, it worked perfectly fine

Comment: Height:100% is on the sidebar .sidebar which the .card is inside

Comment: Sorry, if I'm being stupid, I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: Don't worry, you're not. I just didn't know your **.sidebar** div was there, cause it wasn't  visible in the question's code. I've updated the answer. This should do it. The feedback even grows upwards.

Comment: Thanks, for you're help, I've tried your code though it doesn't seem to put the .feedback at the bottom of the screen, it's appearing just below the card body.

Comment: Strange on my machine it's working perfectly fine. Which browser are you using? have you tried to prefix the css with [AutoPrefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io)? And the **.card** is right inside the **.sidebar** div, right?

Comment: I'm using chrome, yup the .card is inside the .sidebar. It doesn't seem to work in this js fiddle either?

Comment: Dude that is a different HTML structure than in your question...... Your question says **.feedback** is inside **.card**. In your JSFiddle **.feedback** is a HTML sibling to **.card**. Of course it doesn't work....  set `min-height: 100vh`, `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` on you **.sidebar** and `flex: 1` on the **.card**. Was explained in the link I provided you with btw. Please if you want people to help you, give them the correct HTML in your question.

Comment: Sorry you're right I got the jsfiddle wrong, but the one in the question is the structure I tried you're code with, though it still doesn't work, and doesn't seem to work in this jsfiddle with the correct structure https://jsfiddle.net/0o2m52we/

Comment: Okay browser compatibility problems I guess. In my case it worked without setting 'height: 100vh` on the **.side-bar**, too. That is one way of doing it. Or just set `min-height: 100vh` on the **.card**. That worked for me in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `position: fixed` to the div.feedback

Comment: Thank-you this mostly works, however when the content in the card that the feedback is below reaches the bottom of the screen. The feedback div overlaps the content, I'd rather the feedback to be pushed down when this happens. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The Flexbox approach should cover that

Comment: In that case `fixed` is not a good idea, the JHolub solution should work